# Floating Action Button is positioned wrong on pre lollipop devices

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library

I've a weird behaviour problem:

on any device or emulator with a version lower than lollipop the floating action button and other components which float over the toolbar(e.g. the popup of a Spinner) are positioned wrong. They seem to move based on the value of the app:elevation, but even app:elevation="0" doesn't position them equal to lollipop devices.

EDIT: 
I just wanted to explain the behavior of the FAB better. When i add an elevation tag on a pre lollipop device to the fab, its x and y coordinates increase. On a lollipop device the elevation tag has no influence on the position.

EDIT 2:
After some experiments I found out that the problem is that the layout size increases on pre lollipop devices to draw the shadow. This also increases the click able area. This behaviour makes it impossible to create 2 different layouts for lollipop and pre lollipop  devices, because the behaviour and size of the FAB are just wrong. On lollipop devices the layout is (as wanted) 40dp * 40dp and the FAB draws its shadow on the layout below it.

Layout:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:id="@+id/id_drawer_layout">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/primaryColor"
        android:id="@+id/id_toolbar"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
            android:id="@+id/id_toolbar_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/id_swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_below="@id/id_toolbar"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_below="@id/id_toolbar"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/id_filemanager_recycler_view"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_below="@id/id_toolbar"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/id_floating_action_button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:elevation="30dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="288dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:id="@+id/id_main_navigation_view"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer_main"/>
```

Pre Lollipop
[image]

Lollipop
[image]

Comment: Why not create 2 layouts, one within layout-v21, and one for previous versions. You can adjust accordingly

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The solution is to put your `FloatingActionButton` inside `android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`.

This is what i'm using

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp"
        app:elevation="6dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

You can modify this code to meet your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I will try this solution as soon as possible

Comment: Make sure that your `FloatingActionButton` is a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout`. Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: sadly this doesnt work too. The problem is that the layout bounds of the 2 fabs are diffrent between the 2 versions. On lollipop devices the fab is as wanted 40dp*40dp on the other hand on pre lollipop devices the fab is much bigger more like 200dp*200dp. The image of the fab on the pre lollipop devices is positioned in the middle of this too big layout. But the to left corners of the 2 layouts are both at the right position -> only the size is wrong between the two versions.

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines to your FloatingActionButton tag, also change the appBar in my code snippet to the id of the layout you want to attach FloatingActionButton to.

```
app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBar"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|end"
```

Comment: ty for the answer, but sadly it doesnt work. The fab is still placed wrong. The fab seems to move absed on the value of the elevation tag. The higher the elevation is the more the button moves to the right and bottom.